# MinGW + Eclipse: Type invalid conversion from 'void

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, mingw

String:

```
glDebugMessageCallbackARB(&DebugOutputCallback, NULL);
```

Give me error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type invalid conversion from 'void
>   (**attribute**((**stdcall**)) *)(GLenum, GLenum, GLuint, GLenum,
>   GLsizei, const GLchar*, GLvoid*) {aka void
>   (**attribute**((**stdcall**)) *)(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned
>   int, unsigned int, int, const char*, void*)}' to 'GLDEBUGPROCARB {aka
>   void (**attribute**((**stdcall**)) *)(unsigned int, unsigned int,
>   unsigned int, unsigned int, int, const char*, const void*)}'
>   [-fpermissive]

Please tell me what wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is trying to tell you that the signature of your callback function should be

```
void (*)(GLenum, GLenum, GLuint, GLenum, GLsizei, GLchar, GLvoid const*)
```

The last parameter of the callback you are passing is `GLvoid*`, when it should be `GLvoid const*`.